# Perfomance no MySQL com InnoDB em tabela de grande massa de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, innodb

Atualmente possuo uma tabela com cerca de 6 milhões de registros que por sua vez executam uma grande quantidade de operações de I/O, sendo assim na concepção do projeto optei por utilizar o **InnoDB ao invés do MyISAM** no MySQL, afinal, o *lock* seria por página e não por tabela.

Porém estou com um enorme problema, a **MAIORIA** das consultas efetuadas nessa tabela é através de um ** período de data (datetime)**. Por conceito procurei **particioná-la**, porém me deparei com essa **limitação do InnoDB**

O que vocês sugerem para melhorar a performance dessas consultas? Levando em consideração que tenho uma limitação muito grande de hardware?

Segue abaixo a estrutura da tabela.

```sql
  CREATE TABLE `sensores` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `equipamento_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `data_hora` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `valor_primario` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `valor_secundario` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_sensor_equipamento_idx` (`equipamento_id`),
    KEY `data_hora` (`data_hora`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_sensor_equipamento_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`equipamento_id`) REFERENCES `equipamento` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3515782247 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

A operação se consiste em inúmeros "sensores" escrevendo informações de leitura de equipamentos nessa tabela a cada 15 segundos.

A maioria das querys efetuadas são semelhantes a instrução

```sql
SELECT * FROM sensores WHERE data_hora BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Você pode detalhar um pouco mais sobre a estrutura desta tabela e que tipo de alterações, inserções e exclusões ela costuma sofrer? Que tipo de consultas são efetuadas? Sem isso, fica difícil dar respostas úteis.

Comment: O grande trunfo do InnoDB são as TRANSACTIONS, se você não usa não tem realmente motivo pra optar por InnoDB. O MyISAM é bem mais rápido pra consulta.

Comment: @Victor, me desculpe pela ausência de informação, editei a questão e coloquei a estrutura da tabela.

Comment: @Havenard, realmente, mais tenho muita escrita também, e o tempo de resposta delas, são muito importantes. No negócio é dificil dizer qual operação é mais importante.

Answer (score 5):

Uma seleção simples dessa não deveria ser nenhum bicho de sete cabeças pro MySQL executar, mesmo numa tabela de 6 milhões de registros.

Você deve no entanto certificar-se que os campos envolvidos na condição sejam indexados, nesse caso o campo `data_hora`, pra permitir o MySQL fazer a busca de forma binária e muito mais eficiente.

Veja se criando o seguinte índice a performance melhora:

```
CREATE INDEX `data_hora` ON `sensores` (`data_hora`);
```

Comment: No caso do indice ser criado em uma coluna do tipo date_time, ele iria criar um indice para cada "segundo" ? Você sabe como o MySQL se comportaria ?

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Ele cria os índices para os valores que estão na tabela, não existe essa de "para cada segundo" ou qualquer outra unidade de tempo existente. Os índices em geral tem o formato de uma árvore B.

Comment: O índice é uma espécie de metatabela que contém os ponteiros de cada registro organizados pelo campo especificado. Como eles estão em ordem, o MySQL tem a oportunidade de fazer busca binária na tabela.

Comment: Um outro recurso que você pode usar é aumentar o cache do InnoDB, isso vai fazer com que mais informação, possívelmente até a tabela inteira, fique carregada na memória RAM pronta para realizar buscas rápidas. Se eu não me engano isso é feito ajustando o tamanho do `innodb_buffer_pool_size` no arquivo `my.cnf`. Porém é fundamental que o seu servidor tenha memória suficiente pra comportar o MySQL.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Se eu adicionar em uma tabela com o campo data indexado, três datas, uma em 1950, uma em 2000 e a outra em 2050, o índice conterá apenas 3 entradas e não algumas bilhões. Então fica tranquilo quanto a isso.

Comment: @Victor, certo, compreendo, quando digo um a cada segundo é referente ao negócio e ao comportamento dos meus sensores, suponhamos que eu tenha um registro em 29/01/2014 00:00:01, outro um segundo depois, 29/01/2014 00:00:02, e assim por diante. Sendo assim, eu teria um valor de indice por segundo, entende ? Não sei até que ponto a criação de um indice nessa coluna seria interessante.

Comment: @Havenard, obrigado pela dica, realmente não vai ter como fugir, vou ter que fazer um upgrade de hardware. Obrigado !

Comment: @MauroAlexandre O tamanho do índice é limitado pelo número de registros. O índice primário (que indexa pela chave primária) já faz isso. Este índice secundário nunca seria maior que o primário.

Comment: Mas é. Você olha pra tabela e vê que os registros já estão naturalmente organizados por data, mas você tem um cérebro capaz de detectar esse padrão, o MySQL não. Ele não é inteligente, ele não percebe isso por mais óbvio que seja. Você precisa ensinar pra ele, e a maneira de fazer isso é criando um índice. Sem o índice o MySQL vai burramente ler todos os registros da tabela procurando os que estão dentro do período especificado.

Answer (score 4):

### Explicação curta

- Tune o InnoDB para permitir que a tabela fique em memória
- Tune o InnoDB para sincronizar alterações a cada 1 segundo em vez de todo o tempo
- Reformule sua tabela. Remova índices desnecessários, ou acrescente novos

Configurações que recomendo que não esqueça de tunar são `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (para permitir que o banco fique em memória RAM e reduza I/O), `innodb_flush_method` (evitar que o OS duplique cache, requer teste) e `innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit`. Outras podem ser vistas na referência no final desta resposta.

### Explicação longa

Particionar não deve ajudar muito no seu caso. Como seu problema é de I/O, a tendência de melhorar e usar SSD em vez de HDD, ou então minimizar o acesso ao disco.

Como apenas trocar para SSD vai deixar rápido, porém ainda assim não muito rápido, é melhor você ter memória suficiente e configurar seu MySQL/MariaDB para permitir que toda a tabela permaneça em memória RAM e limitar para que o banco de dados escreva no disco alterações em intervalos não menores do que a cada segundo, pois mesmo que o banco esteja completamente em memória é uma exigência que haja essa sincronização.

Quanto a usar `Engine MyISAM`, ele não pode apresentar desempenho pior que `Engine InnoDB` quando updates e writes são altos. o `Engine MEMORY` pode ser útil em alguns casos específicos, mas deve ser usado como ultimo recurso, e não raro `Engine InnoDB` pode ser quase tão eficiente quanto o `Engine MEMORY` se for bem configurado.

Sei que pode ter um hardware limitado, porém vai ser difícil querer otimizar isso sem ter pelo menos memória suficiente. Nessa situação, o melhor que pode fazer é a recomendação do parágrafo seguinte.

Quanto a reformular sua tabela, se o seu modo de uso costuma ser apenas alterar com frequência apenas registros recentes, é útil criar duas tabelas, e, eventualmente, mover da tabela recente para tabela antiga. Faço isso com tabelas que tem muito mais dados do que a sua e funciona muito bem. Mas, claro, isso só é util se você não tem UPDATEs em dados antigos. Essa divisão de dados é mais eficiente do que usar particionamento se for bem planejada e permite cache com maior facilidade.

### Referências que você deveria ler

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb.html
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html
3. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/
4. https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/comparing_innodb_to_myisam_performance

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição. Infelizmente o engine MEMORY não é algo possivel no momento, porém pensei em utiliza-lo para criar uma tabela secundaria e armazenar os últimos registros, que de fato, são os mais acessados. Você qualifica isso como uma boa opção ?

Comment: Mauro, tunar o banco para permitir que o InnoDB esteja em memória é diferente de setar seu formato como MEMORY.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre editei a resposta e deixei explícito configurações e links para referências confiáveis e detalhadas sobre como otimizar InnoDB para leitura e escritas pesadas. Ainda que dividir em duas tabelas (uma recente, outra antiga) seja uma opção, se puder otimizar para caber em memória já deve ter performance aceitável e evitar a complicação adicional de ter que sincronizar duas tabelas diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

- Uma coisa que vc pode fazer é seguir a sugestão do @Havernard, se não
  a tabela não têm modificações constantes.
- A outra é na sua consulta trazer apenas o que vc realmente precisa,
  nada de **SELECT * FROM**, e se certificar que o campo pelo qual vc vai fazer o filtro não esteja nulo
- pode também fazer a pesquisa com paginação, pq possivelmente vc não
  vai precisar visualizar centenas de milhares de registros de uma
  unica vez
- Juntamente com tudo isso vc pode indexar a coluna, mas vc teria quer ver qual o tipo do seu campo de data, pq a perfomace pode variar de acordo com o tipo (date, datetime ou timestamp)

Comment: A utilização do "*" não obteve alteração de perfomance, acredito que por conta da quantidade de colunas ser insignificante. Porém a indexação de fato é importante, e me preocupa.

Caso eu indexe a coluna de data, no formato DATETIME, ele criaria um valor de indice para cada "segundo" ? Isso me preocupa pelo fato do indice crescer proporcionalmente a quantidade de valores.

Answer (score 1):

Não que esta resposta exatamente responda a sua pergunta. Mas, considerando que os registros inseridos nunca são alterados ou excluídos e considerando que você faz buscas baseadas no tempo, então o foco do particionamento é no tempo.

Uma forma bem simples de particionar no tempo é começar a criar tabelas por período de tempo. Algo do tipo `sensores_11_2013`, `sensores_12_2013`, `sensores_01_2014`, etc.

Comment: Realmente, eu havia cogitado essa possibilidade, expugrar os dados dos periodos anteriores e deixar apenas os ultimos na tabela principal. Porém a aplicação gera relatorios de periodos anteriores e consequentemente isso me obrigaria a efetuar alterações constantes nas consultas da aplicação, ação essa que é inviavel para o negócio.